# jQuery hide only the empty element

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide

I'm working on a tagging feature and the wrapping element for the tag (span class="tag") is showing without content. I need to hide the empty one and show the tags with content. The problem is my logic is affecting all the tags, not just the empty one. How can I target just the empty tag?

```
 $(".tag:empty").hide();
        $('.tag_btn').live('click', function() {
             if (!$('.tag:empty')){
                 $('.tag').show();
             }
        });
```

Comment: How about hiding the `.tag_btn`that's right next to the empty ones? `$(".tag:empty").sibling('.tag_btn').hide();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Ok so when you click `.tag_btn`, you want to display all the non-empty `.tag`s ? Try this:

```
$('.tag_btn').live('click', function() 
{
    $('.tag:not(:empty)').show();
});
```

Comment: +1 Your answer is better than mine. Good catch seeing that $('.tag:empty') is a selector and not a boolean...

Comment: tag_btn is the selector for the button which generates the tag.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware you could apply the seudo-class :not in jQuery. I'm having a new issue of the tag still being hidden after '.tag_btn' is clicked. It's not until the second tag is created that the two non-empty tags are displayed. I figured the live event would catch that. Oh well..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what could be going on, but would this alternate way work?

```
$('.tag').each(function(){
    var tag = $(this);
    if ($.trim(tag.text() != ""))
    {
        tag.show();
    }
});
```